# printing the address stored in a pointer using write

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-address

Can I print an address stored in a pointer using write function only ? (from unistd.h lib).

```
    int c = 6;
    void *ptr = &c;
    
    printf("%p",ptr);
```

I'd like to get the same results as the code above using write not printf.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can format the address value into a `char[]` manually and then provide that buffer to `write` function.

Comment: I'd love it if you can clarify your answer with a code or a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply format the address into a char buffer on your own and pass it to `write`.

Normally you would just use `sprintf` to do that but if you don't like `printf` you might not like `sprintf`, too.

Nevertheless I will show that first:

```c
  int c = 6;
  void *ptr = &c;

  char outbuf[2*sizeof(void*)+1];
  sprintf("%x", p);
  write(fd, outbuf, strlen(outbuf));
```

Without `sprintf` and with MCVE:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  int c = 6;
  void *ptr = &c;

  static const char hex_digits[]="0123456789abcdef";
  size_t addr_size = sizeof (void*);
  char outbuf[2*addr_size+1];
  int i;
  uintptr_t val =(intptr_t) ptr;

  int nibble;
  for (i = addr_size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    nibble = val % 0x10;
    val /= 0x10;
    outbuf[2*i+1] = hex_digits[nibble];

    nibble = val % 0x10;
    val /= 0x10;
    outbuf[2*i] = hex_digits[nibble];
  }
  outbuf[2*addr_size] = 0;
  printf("%s\n", outbuf);
  // replace with write(fd, outbuf, strlen(outbuf))  for your needs
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should use `uintptr_t`, not `intptr_t`.  `nibble` might become negative else